# Z3 Java API toString() method Bug

Tags: java, api, z3

```
import com.microsoft.z3.BoolExpr;
import com.microsoft.z3.Context;
import com.microsoft.z3.EnumSort;
import com.microsoft.z3.Expr;
import com.microsoft.z3.Solver;
import com.microsoft.z3.Status;
import com.microsoft.z3.Symbol;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class AdvSMT {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> cfg = new HashMap<>();
        cfg.put("model", "true");
        Context ctx = new Context(cfg);
        Solver z3 = ctx.mkSolver(); 
        Symbol name0 = ctx.mkSymbol("Enum0");
        EnumSort Enum0 = ctx.mkEnumSort(name0, ctx.mkSymbol("In_Air"),
                ctx.mkSymbol("On_Ground"), ctx.mkSymbol("None"));
        Symbol name1 = ctx.mkSymbol("Enum1"); 
        EnumSort Enum1 = ctx.mkEnumSort(name1, ctx.mkSymbol("True"), 
                ctx.mkSymbol("False"), ctx.mkSymbol("None")); 
        Expr var_0 = ctx.mkConst("var_0", Enum0);
        Expr var_1 = ctx.mkConst("var_1", Enum1); 
        BoolExpr assertion_0 = ctx.mkEq(var_0, Enum0.getConst(2));
        BoolExpr assertion_1 = ctx.mkEq(var_1, Enum1.getConst(2));
        z3.add(assertion_0);
        z3.add(assertion_1);

        // print out 
        if(z3.check()==Status.SATISFIABLE){
            System.out.println(z3.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will print out the following SMT formulas:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Enum0 (In_Air) (On_Ground) (None))))
(declare-datatypes () ((Enum1 (True) (False) (None))))
(declare-fun var_0 () Enum0)
(declare-fun var_1 () Enum1)
(assert (= var_0 None))
(assert (= var_1 None))
```

However, those formulas will not be accepted by Z3 since the last two lines should be printed out as:

```
(assert (= var_0 (as None Enum0)))
(assert (= var_1 (as None Enum1)))
```

Is this a bug in Z3 API?

Comment: If you have to ask, that would indicate that you're not very familiar with Z3, which makes it very unlikely that you would stumble upon a bug (not impossible, but statistically unlikely). You say "will not be accepted", does that mean you haven't even tried?

Comment: I tried to send the print out SMT formulas to both Z3 and CVC4, and it will report out a syntax error.

Comment: File a bug report? Checking any existing ones of course.

Comment: It will be very helpful to get some inputs/suggestions from the Z3 developers regarding if this is a bug, or if we should not use the "toString()" method to generate SMT formulas using Z3 API, or if there is any other workaround to generate SMT formulas conforming to the SMT-LIB2 standard with the Z3 API.

Comment: This is StackOverflow, not the Z3 developer's forum. Find their bugtracker.